# Strategies for maintaining a reference to a file after it was moved or renamed?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, open-files, rename

I've had a mac at work lately, and was amazed to see that Xcode would still find my latest project after I renamed its folder and moved it someplace else.

Now I understand that this is the result of a heavy infrastructure at work, but I was wondering if it would be possible to somehow come up with similar functionality for the rest of the Unix world ?

Comment: Mac OS X __is__ in the Unix world.

Comment: Indeed, edited.

Comment: Does it track changes no matter where you made the change? For example if you used `mv /path/to/project /new/path/to/project` would it still find it? Or are you moving/renaming in Xcode? Most IDEs will be able to trivially change/rename/move project files and still find them just fine.

Comment: _How_ did you move the project? _Where_ did you move it to? I can certainly imagine that if you use Xcode to move it, it's a no-brainer. If Xcode uses some convention ("all projects are under ~/Projects") and you moved it around there, it could just look there (or even search all over your $HOME for stuff that looks like projects, today's machines have enough performance that you wouldn't necessarily notice).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well on Linux you could use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to track changes to your files. Inotify is in-kernel and has bindings to many different languages allowing you to quickly script such functionality if the app you are working with does not support inotify yet.

Comment: Sounds like it could be used to store ancient pathes to a file, and with a file-not-found-hook lookup the current path. Nice